# ActiveCell.Formula Error 438 'Object Doesn't Support'

Tags: vba, excel

this code is supposed to calculate the monthly returns of a stock provided from sheet1 on a new sheet i created stock_returns. It will calculate the first box and then auto fill the rest of the data depending on variables j,k and l. However the error keeps coming up for the first activecell line and I do not know how else to change it.

```
'select stock names and paste to next sheet named monthly returns
Dim a As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

j = stocknum + 3
k = stocknum + 5
l = stocknum + stocknum + 5

Worksheets("stock_returns").Activate

ActiveCell.FormulaR3C2 = "=('Sheet1'!B9-'Sheet1'!B10)/'Sheet1'!B10"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:Bj" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("Bk").Value = Range("B2") - Range("Bj")
Range("Bk").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Bk:Bl" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 0):

> ActiveCell.**FormulaR3C2** = "=('Sheet1'!B9-'Sheet1'!B10)/'Sheet1'!B10"

There is no [.Range.FormulaR3C2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823188.aspx) but there is a [Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823188.aspx). This refers to the [xlR1C1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176159(v=office.11).aspx) [Reference Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176159(v=office.11).aspx) of cell addressing used in the formula supplied but you are using the [xlA1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176159(v=office.11).aspx) style in your formula.

Use the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) instead.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=('Sheet1'!B9-'Sheet1'!B10)/'Sheet1'!B10"
```

Alternately with the [Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823188.aspx) as,

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=('Sheet1'!R9C2-'Sheet1'!R10C2)/'Sheet1'!R10C2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced your VBA will compile even with the adjustment suggested by @Jeeped. I am not sure what results you want but at least you should get some results from the version below:

```
Sub Stance()
Dim a As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

j = stocknum + 3
k = stocknum + 5
l = stocknum + stocknum + 5
Lastrow = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("stock_returns").Activate

Cells(3, 2).Formula = "=('Sheet1'!B9-'Sheet1'!B10)/'Sheet1'!B10"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & j + Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("B" & k).Value = Range("B2") - Range("B" & j)
Range("B" & k).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & k & ":B" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```